# Pattern matching in Haskell case statements

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I came across the following piece of code:

```
lala :: [[Int]] -> Bool
lala b = case b of
   (a:_) | Just (b, _) <- uncons a -> True
   other -> False
```

While I understand that the function checks that the first element of the list is not empty (there are better ways of writing this, but that's not the point), I don't fully understand the pattern matching happening in the case statement. Is the left arrow in this case simply pattern matching on the `uncons` call? Can this style of pattern matching be nested? This almost seems like a list comprehension syntax, are there other places where this type of pattern matching can be used?

Comment: This is a [pattern guard](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pattern_guard). What do you mean by nested?

Comment: I find the use of `b` in `Just (b, _) <- ..` to be horrible. GHC should warn about that, since it bears _no_relation to the outermost `b`. Just pretend the pattern is `Just (_,_) <- ...`, since that `b` is not even used. (If it were used, the innermost `b` bindings would shadow the outermost one -- it's better to rename `b` to something else in that case)

Comment: @chi Or better, `Just _`. Or really, why introduce this whole confusing `uncons` at all? Just write `case b of {((_:_):_) -> True; otherwise = False}`: a list whose first item is a nonempty list.

Comment: @amalloy I agree. I guess the code was meant to be an example about how to use `uncons` with pattern guards. If so, perhaps a more insightful example would have been better, though.